# spring boot take interface as bean impletation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

when I config spring boot 1.5 with mybatis multi-datasource, the classic error "Parameter 0 of constructor in SimsCardTypeController required a single bean, but 2 were found:aImpl,A" come out.
here is the related classes:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/xx")
public class SimsCardTypeController extends RestBase {
    private A simsCardTypeService;
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    public SimsCardTypeController(A simsCardTypeService, HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.simsCardTypeService = simsCardTypeService;
        this.request = request;
    }
..
}
@Component
public class RestBase {}
interface A{}  
@Service
class AImpl implements A{}
```

I don't know any possible config leading Spring take A as a bean. How can I debug this situation?

Comment: Can u post your complete code with the exception?

Comment: I post the related classes and exception

Comment: Do 2 classes implement the interface A?

Comment: no,I've check this possibility, and the exception mention A as a bean.

Comment: can u post ur complete project on github and share d link?

Comment: it's a rather large production project,I don't sure I can separate the related and reproduce this problem. Do you have any idea how this exception can happen?

Comment: it can happen if there are 2 classes implementing the same interface and both being managed by spring.

Comment: what happens if you change the `simsCardTypeService` to `aImpl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with mybatis scan, mybatis transform A interface to a mapper.I share a tip to debug the similar problem:
1.qualify the strange interface A to the bean which Spring ask for

```
 @Autowired
 public SimsCardTypeController(@Qualifier(value="A")A simsCardTypeService, HttpServletRequest request){}
```

2. add breakpoint in the body,you can see what the simsCardTypeService exact is. In my case,it's something like xxMapper, so I can relate it to mybatis scan.

thanks